# Android Mobile App - is this a good use-case for Google Cloud Service?

Tags: android, mobile, google-cloud-endpoints, betfair

I'm working on an Android mobile application which retrieves data from Betfair and displays the results.

The Betfair API is basically a Web Service that returns JSON, and it's generic enough to return appropriate data based on customized input.

Now my question is, would using a Google cloud app engine bring any value given I'm already retrieving data from a web service (betfair API)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "no" - as your Android app can talk directly to the service to get data via JSON. To add kind of Google Cloud service seems would act as an unnecessary intermediary.

Comment: Thanks, now what if I wanted to add a layer of business logic in between? For example, retrieve the data via the betfair API, apply some filtering based on user preferences (account setup) and display results?

Comment: Business logic COULD be added that way (back-end) but it still introduces another layer, and I'm still not hearing a reason why it would NEED to be. For example, if your backend was going to pull, store and make HISTORICAL data (which would not be available via betfair) - THAT would be a reason to need it. If you wanted to run your service as a paid one - or offer web (non-android) access - those might be good reasons, too.

Comment: ...or offer asynchronous "push notifications" on certain events - or if you had some reason to require periodic "batch" processing of data - at times when the user might not be connected/running - or you wanted/needed such "core logic" to run in one place - and then offer data (per user) across multiple different front-ends without each front-end needing to have its on configuration, or do all the data processing work.